# Finding correct list containing a specific i in a collection of lists

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures

I'm in the process of designing a data structure (using only linked lists and arrays) with the following complexity requirements:
-initialize 0(1)

- get,delete,modify by index O(sqrt(n))
- add_last 0(sqrt(n))

In order to cover all original n elements I've decided to make a collection of lists numbered 1,2,...,√3n  (a hint was given the sum of integers from 1 to n is bounded by 1/3n^2 and n^2)
each of the ordered and also ordered with respect to each other (all elements in list i
are smaller that those in list i+1)
that way the "longest" lists has sqrt(3n) elements so I can linear search in it after I determine which lists contains the given element.
I'm having trouble coming up with the formula to find the list in which to search for, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your post to specify the data structure more carefully.  Is this supposed to be a list/dynamic array data structure, with an additional add_last operation?  Please specify what the parameters and the intended behavior of the add_last operation is.  What's the context where you encountered this?  Can you explain the motivation  or credit the original source where you saw this task?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159659/755